# How many sub lattices of $aZ+bZ$ Have index 3?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integer-lattices

So consider the lattices $aZ+bZ$ for any vectors $a$ and $b$. And Z means all integers. I have found 3 so far:

$2aZ+2bZ$ and $3aZ +bZ$ and $aZ+3bZ$ Are there anymore? Am I right? This question basically means to find sub groups of index $3$ right?

Comment: Are you certain that $2a\Bbb Z+2b\Bbb Z$ has index $3$?

Comment: A sub lattice  would be generated by adding vector $a$ which gives the coset $aZ+2bZ$ and adding vector $b$ gives $2aZ+bZ$ . These three contain all the elements and generate $aZ+bZ$ right? Sorry I am new to lattices and really confused

Comment: I presume $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent? If so, this is basically counting index three subgroups of $\Bbb Z^2$. Each such contains $3\Bbb Z^2$, so that reduces to counting index three subgroups of $\Bbb Z^2/3\Bbb Z^2$, which is a nice finite Abelian group.

Comment: @Dhdh consider element $a+b$ . Firstly $a+b$ does not belong to $2a\Bbb Z+2b\Bbb Z$ as $2a\Bbb Z+2b\Bbb Z$ contains only multiples of $2a+2b$. Secondly $a+b$ does not belong to $a\Bbb Z+2b\Bbb Z$ as $a\Bbb Z+2b\Bbb Z$ contains only multiples of $a+2b$ and $b\ne k 2 b$. Similarly and thirdly $a+b$ does not belong to $2a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z$ as $2a\Bbb Z+b\Bbb Z$ contains only multiples of $2a+b$ and $a \ne k 2 a$. (Where $k$ is integer). What you are missing is $a+b+2a\Bbb Z+2b\Bbb Z$